# Queue in django/python

Tags: python, django

I have developed a django REST API. I send request/data to it to perfrom a task and it does it nicely. Though, In a way, I can send it multiple request/data to perfrom the task on each of them. The issue is that server where the task gets performed has limited memory and I need to perform these task one by one. So, I am thinking to have a queue system at django pipeline which can maintain the reqeust on hold till the task in front of the queue is done.
I am not sure if I am on right path, but not sure if celery is the option to solve my issue?
It seems a simple task and I didnt understand if celery is what i need. Can you point me what should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your API as is, then celery will not help you. It's a good idea to keep API calls as short as possible. If you have some longer job done during API calls (sending emails, for example), then you better use celery. But the only thing you can get as a response to your API is that the task was queued.

Comment: I am looking for a way to send the request to process some data to django and put that request in queue. The request will be processed one by one. I think celery is not for that purpose. https://pypi.org/project/django-queue-manager/  this might be helpful seems

Comment: Yes, you can do this with celery. You can set it up so that it runs several tasks in parallel (depends on the number of cores you have) or only in 1 thread.